# End tag is missing matching start tag

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, visual-studio-2013, warnings

I have the following code/markup in my `Index.cshtml`:

```
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Clients", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <p>
        Title: @Html.TextBox("search") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
    }
</p>
```

Visual Studio 2013 warns me that the last line (`</p>`) doesn't have a start tag. I don't have any other `<p>` or `</p>` tags in the document. What's going on?

Full warning message: `End tag is missing matching start tag`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two important facts about paragraphs:

- The end tag for `p` elements is optional.
- `p` elements cannot contain other `p` elements.

This means that:

1. The first `p` start tag opens the first `p` element.
2. The second `p` start tag closes the first `p` element then opens the second `p` element.
3. The first `p` end tag closes the second `p` element.
4. The second `p` end tag has no open `p` element to close.